# Why the close method in Qt does not work correctly?

Tags: qt, usb, exit

I'm coding in Qt. I have a USB communication with Cypress FX2LP. When the device is not connected through USB cable, i should show a dialog box with OK-Abort Option. when the User click on Ok, i Re-Check USB Connection. It works good. but when User click on abort, I should completely close the program. The abort option doesn't work and Re-show the OK-Abort Dialog. What is the problem with my code?
This is part of My code(Main.cpp/ Mainwindow / My_Receive_Data_Thread(My USB communication thread) ):

Main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QIcon>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    a.setQuitOnLastWindowClosed(true);
    a.processEvents();
    MainWindow w;
    w.setAttribute(Qt::WA_QuitOnClose);
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

My_Receive_Data_Thread:

```
My_Receive_Data_Thread::~My_drawing_object(){
}
void My_Receive_Data_Thread::Send_command_packet(){
    CCyUSBDevice USBDevice;// CCyUSBDevice recognize only Cypress Devices
    short int numDevices = USBDevice.DeviceCount();
    if(numDevices==0)
        emit show_message("warning","USB Device not connected!");
}
```

MainWindow:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent):QMainWindow(parent),ui(new Ui::MainWindow){
    ui->setupUi(this);
    My_Receive_Data_Thread_1= new My_Receive_Data_Thread(this);
    connect(My_Receive_Data_Thread_1,SIGNAL(show_message(QString,QString)),this,SLOT(show_message_box(QString,QString)),static_cast<Qt::ConnectionType>(Qt::UniqueConnection));
    connect(this,SIGNAL(Send_command_packet()),My_Receive_Data_Thread_1,SLOT(Send_command_packet()),static_cast<Qt::ConnectionType>(Qt::UniqueConnection));
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow(){
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::show_message_box(QString title,QString text){
    QMessageBox::StandardButton reply; 

 reply=QMessageBox::question(this,title,text,QMessageBox::Abort|QMessageBox::Ok);
   if(reply==QMessageBox::Abort)
      close();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Send_command_packet()` is probably called multiple times, so it emits a lot of `show_message()` that are all queued.

The first of them queues the call to `close()`, but there are still other `show_message()` to process.

Add a `bool m_closed` to the `MainWindow`, set it to `true` when closing, and check it in `show_show_message_box()`.

```
void MainWindow::show_message_box(QString title,QString text){
    if (!m_closing){
        QMessageBox::StandardButton reply; 

        reply=QMessageBox::question(this,title,text,QMessageBox::Abort|QMessageBox::Ok);
        if(reply==QMessageBox::Abort){
            m_closing = true;
            close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, the `My_Receive_Data_Thread` can't do anything about it. It has probably already emitted a bunch of new `show_message()` signals during the execution of one `MainWindow::show_message_box()`.

Comment: The function `void MainWindow::show_message_box(QString title,QString text)`.

Comment: Thanks Velkan! It works good but in a special situation. If the device is not connected from the program run beginning, close() method doesn't work. Probably because the window not opened yet so to we can close it.